# Entity metadata wrapper, get field collection in field collection

Tags: entities

I want to get (and to set after) the value of a field collection in a field collection (multidimensional field content).

This is my code :

```
// The node is a custom content.

// I get the list of first collections fields.
$temp = field_collection_get($node,'field_top');
// Shows the structure you can see below in the screenshot.
dpm($temp->value()[0]);

// Now, I want to get the value of field_website_informations.
// I've tried several ways but I couldn't find the right way.
// The following line returns an error.
$testage = entity_metadata_wrapper($temp->value()[0], 'field_website_informations');
```

Is it possible to do with the Entity API?

The screenshot :

[image: The screenshot]

Comment: Do yourself a favour @user2137454 by learning how to set-up and use a php debugger like xdebug. You'll never look back to `dpm()` ever again, particularly in Drupal with its heavy reliance on multi-dimensional arrays to pass around data.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Let's say you have a content type with a field collection named `field_collection_parent`, which has a field collection in it named `field_collection_child`, which has a field in it named `field_child`.

```
// First you need to wrap the node with entity_metadata_wrapper
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

// To get the value of field_child:
$value = $node_wrapper
           ->field_collection_parent
           ->field_collection_child
           ->field_child
           ->value();

// UPDATE: If a field accepts multiple values, treat it like an array
// The following line would get the first value of field_collection_child in the 
// first field_collection_parent.
$value = $node_wrapper
           ->field_collection_parent[0]
           ->field_collection_child[0]
           ->value();

// To set/modify the value of field_child
$node_wrapper
  ->field_collection_parent
  ->field_collection_child
  ->field_child
  ->set('Some new value');

// To save the node after modifying
$node_wrapper->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for help =) 
When I try :
    $value = $temp->field_top->field_website_informations->value(); 
I obtain this error : 
Undefined property: EntityListWrapper::$field_website_informations

I don't understand... My custom content contain a field collection named "field_top". 
In the admin panel for field collection, I can see the "field top" who contain the sub-collection field "field_website_informations"

Comment: Ok, as it seems, the field `field_top` is a multi-value field. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: It's ok with your update !
ReeeaaalllyyyYYY thanks guy from french country!

Comment: Glad that it works :)

Comment: please see my solution: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144466/change-values-of-nested-fields-with-entity-metadata-wrapper/307791#307791