# Change values of nested fields with entity_metadata_wrapper

Tags: 7, entities, files

The background of this question is that I'm trying to migrate data from Drupal 6 [Imagefield Extended](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagefield_extended) to Drupal 7 [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) (with [File Entity Inline](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity_inline)). See also https://www.drupal.org/node/974888

First I tried to understand how entities work and how they can be extracted and manipulated using [Entity Metadata Wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers). That seems to work ok, for example, I can get the values of my imagefield like this:

```
$nid = 103025;
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid);
$images = $node_wrapper->field_image->value();
```

And it seems that I could change the values of the images with something like this:

```
// Do something with $images
$node_wrapper->field_image->set($images);
$node_wrapper->revision->set(1);
$node_wrapper->save();
```

(For some reason it's not saving the values for the node in my case, but that's another question.)

My problem now is that I have nested fields, i.e. the imagefield has "subfields" for the source and license (that I had added in Drupal 6 using Imagefield Extended). I do get the values of those nested fields in $images - but only in the typical array with `$images[und][0]['value']` and `$images[und][0]['safe_value']`. But there seems to be no way to get those values through the wrapper, for example like

```
$node_wrapper->field_image->field_source->value();
$node_wrapper->field_image->value()->field_source->value();
```

Now I have been trying for hours to figure out how I can change (or populate) those (sub) fields and then save the entire node, but to no avail.

I'm also wondering if it's necessary to do this on a node level as files are also entities, but it seems that there is nothing like `entity_metadata_wrapper('file', $fid);`.

I'd appreciate any hint that could point me in the right direction because the search has been kind of exhausting.

Comment: Have you tried `$node_wrapper->field_image->file->field_source->value()`?

Comment: Hi Clive, that one returns a PHP error: "Call to a member function value() on a non-object".

Comment: Have you managed to confirm that File Entity definitely supports EntityMetadataWrapper? It isn't necessarily something implicit, entity modules can need to explicitly declare their support for it

Comment: Actually ignore that, it does support it. Try inspecting  the results of `$node_wrapper->field_image->getPropertyInfo()` and `$node_wrapper->field_image->file->getPropertyInfo()` to see what fields/properties the system things are available. That might help to shed some light. Feel free to edit them into the question and ping me if you want me to have a look

Comment: Thanks a lot Clive, but I'm still stuck: The first one (´$node_wrapper->field_image->getPropertyInfo()´) leads to the error "Call to undefined method EntityListWrapper::getPropertyInfo()" and the second one (´$node_wrapper->field_image->file->getPropertyInfo()´) to the error "Call to a member function getPropertyInfo() on a non-object".

Comment: What about `$node_wrapper->field_image[0]->getPropertyInfo()`? And then perhaps `$node_wrapper->field_image[0]->file->getPropertyInfo()`. I don't have file entity installed on anything so I'm guessing a bit

Comment: That does work! Thanks for the hint. I'll try with that and then get back to you. But I still have the problem that values aren't saved through ->save().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using what Clive mentioned and with the hint eikes provided, this seems to be a way to accomplish what I want:

```
$nid = 108501;
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($node_wrapper->field_image->value()); $i++) {
  $node_wrapper->field_image[$i]->file->field_source->set('NEW SOURCE');
  $node_wrapper->field_image[$i]->file->field_license->set('NEW LICENSE');
  $node_wrapper->field_image[$i]->file->save();
}

// Just for dev: Check if the values have been saved
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid);
dsm($node_wrapper->field_bild->value());
```

Erroneously I used the `save()` call on the whole node wrapper, but as files are their own entities, the call needs to be on the file, as eikes suggested.

Additionally, I noticed that calling `$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid);` after the above code doesn't reflect the changes (for checking). It seems I need to reload the entity first.

Thanks a lot to both of you!

Comment: I assume that the file you get is a separate entity and you may need to save it as well:

  $node_wrapper->field_image[$i]->file

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to access and update 2 nested levels deep on unlimited values on field collections fields

```
  function set_descuentos_pagos_action($nid) {
  // $raw_node = node_load($nid);  AVOID THIS
  $node = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid);
  // dpm($node->getPropertyInfo());
  // dpm($node);
  $raw_ana = $node->field_ana->value();
  // dpm($raw_ana);
  $num_cotizaciones = count($raw_ana);

  // $i ES EL ITEM DE  CADA COTIZACION
  for ($i=0 ; $i < $num_cotizaciones  ; $i++ ) {
    
    $ana[$i] = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $raw_ana[$i]);
    $fp = $ana[$i]->field_m_fc_pago_texto->value();
    if($fp == 'Trimestral'){
      // get values from parent field collection
      $prima_descuento[$i] = $ana[$i]->field_m_fc_prima_neta_descuento->value();
      $prima_original[$i] = $ana[$i]->field_m_fc_prima_neta->value();
      $factor[$i] = $prima_descuento[$i] / $prima_original[$i];

      // get child field collection
      $raw_recibos = $ana[$i]->field_m_fc_recibo->value();
      $num_recibos[$i] = count($raw_recibos);

      // $j SON LOS PAGOS DE LA ITERACION $i
      for ($j=0; $j < $num_recibos[$i]; $j++) {

        // get current child field collection object
        $value[$j] = $ana[$i]->field_m_fc_recibo[$j]->value();

        // $pago[$j] ES EL PAGO OBJETO
        $pago[$j] = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $value[$j]);
         // dpm($pago[$j]->value());
         // get field value, set value on other field
         $prima = $pago[$j]->field_m_fc_prima_total->value();
         $nuevo_valor = $prima * $factor[$i];
         $pago[$j]->field_m_fc_prima_total_descuento->set($nuevo_valor);
         $pago[$j]->save();
      }

    }
  }

} // end  set_descuento_pagos_cotizacion
```